# How to handle large doctrine Collections and Associations

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm working on a project where I have to collect a lot of data from the database. I'm using Symfony2 (symfony bf1281aebdc842a39ec0eb7438e1ea3fca9b9705) and Doctrine2 (doctrine 3b3186ee98392802a44118cd421a3530119aa7eaand ) as working base.

The Problem I encounter is, that I have to fetch about 15.000 articles. After that, I need to iterate through all of them an fetch more data on base of the article id (there are direct and indirect associations with i.e. (inherited) media or prices, etc...). It's ok for about 50-100 records, but if I want to use more records it takes a lot of ram an time to fetch everything from the database.

Is there a way to iterate through the data without using up all of the remaining ram? Is there a way to tell doctrine to stop using references?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6):

save another line by using:

```
$iterableResult = $doctrine->getManager()->createQuery("SELECT c FROM ENTITY c")->iterate();

while ((list($obj) = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
    // do something with $obj
    $em->detach($obj);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look into using iterative (step-by-step) hydration in Doctrine:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$q  = $em->createQuery("<DQL to select the objects I want>");
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
    // do stuff with the data in the row, $row[0] is always the object
    $em->detach($row[0]); // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be GC'd immediately
}
```

Details from [this article](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing), under *Mass object processing*

Comment: FYI: the link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Hard to answer without more specifics about what you're trying to do, exactly.

Doctrine generally isn't a good fit for major data-crunching like you might be describing.  I have several projects that fall-back on just using DBAL to run raw SQL for things like complicated reports.

That said, if you don't actually need all 15k records loaded at once, then don't load them at once!  Grab 50, process them, free memory, and repeat.  This approach can keep totals as you go, so it's possible to get some aggregate statistics for the whole set.

That said, if you're needing aggregate stuff, you're probably building some kind of "report", and you might well be better off using pure SQL, or even some stored procedures, and don't let the ORM get involved.

Comment: And tell me, in exactly what Symfony driven application could you need 15k records at once? Only data mining needs that much data and thath should not be powered by Symfony.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually another way, but you will not like it. You can use pure mysql :)
When I tried to get 450k objects from database using getRepository("..")->findAll() - it taked hours until I closed script :). So I used code like

```
    $c = $doctrine->getConnection();
    mysql_connect($c->getParams()['host'],$c->getParams()['user'],$c->getParams()['password']);//$link =
    mysql_select_db($c->getParams()['dbname']);
    $qid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM TABLENAME");
    while($i = mysql_fetch_row($qid)) {
        $object = $doctrine->getRepository("...")->find($i[0]);
```

I got first object after **1.7 seconds**, which is absolutely acceptable for me. Except messy code :(

After googling a bit I located you question and [doctrine manuall](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html#mass-object-processing). After rewriting I got code

```
    $iterableResult = $doctrine->getManager()->createQuery("SELECT c FROM ENTITY c")->iterate();

    while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
        $object = $row[0];
    }
```

Code above provided first item in **2.4 seconds**, which is extremely fast, as for the doctrine2 and 450k items in table.

My point is - doctrine2 already have almost anything you need for "real-life" usage, but you still can simplify your life with old school ugly code :)

UPDATE: Dont forget to cascade detach all loaded entities. And in symfony2 you also need to disable SQL logging by running code

```
    $doctrine->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

From doctrine [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results):

```
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $row) {
    $user = $row[0];
    $user->increaseCredit();
    $user->calculateNewBonuses();
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
    ++$i;
}
$em->flush();
```